# Disable DRM in Evince

Tags: pdf, encryption, drm, evince

Is it possible to disable DRM (digital rights management) for PDF files in "Evince" so that encrypted PDF files can be saved?  How do you make this configuration?  The option does not seem to be apparent.

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41295/how-to-save-a-copy-of-a-protected-pdf-form-in-evince

Answer (score 1):

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evince

"Evince used to obey the DRM restrictions of PDF files, which may prevent copying, printing, or converting some PDF files, however this has been made optional, and turned off by default in gconf."

A little googling led to this: http://archive.today/uKxXs

"2007-07-04 at 04:38 Donald Hellen wrote:

> > Does Evince allow you to at least read DRM protected ebooks, if not 
> >     print them? 
> >     What will Evince allow you to do with these DRM protected PDF files?
>
> *cough* gconf-editor *cough* Enable /apps/evince/override_restrictions

Comment: The thing is that I'm using the Windows version of Evince, and I'm not sure what kinds of configuration utilities are supposed to be used for this or how to perform these equivalent configurations.  Evince does not allow me to save an edited copy of a PDF with protections on it.  Evince was installed to "AppData\Local\Apps\Evince-2.32.0.145\bin".  Should I add a configuration file?  Are these config editors something that can be installed in Windows?

Comment: @user553702: OK! I have no idea on how gconf is handled on windows. If you don't need to edit the file afterwards, you could print it and choose save as pdf. If that doesn't do it, do you have to use evince? For example, Okular has DRM setting.